# Counting word occurence with arrays stream in Java 8

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

How I can calculate word frequency in a string with using arrays stream? I'm using Java 8.

Here is my code:

```
String sentence = "The cat has black fur and black eyes";
String[] bites = sentence.trim().split("\\s+");

String in = "black cat";
```

calculate words "black" and "cat" frequency in the sentence. Word "black" frequency is 2 and word "cat" is 1.

**So the goal output is then 3.**

Comment: `Pattern.compile("\\b(black|cat)\\b").splitAsStream(sentence).count()-1`

Comment: @Holger: Nice! But must pad sentence with a dummy word because it does not work when the last word is `cat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String sentence = "The cat has black fur and black eyes";
    String[] bites = sentence.trim().split("\\s+");
    String in = "black cat";
    long i = Stream.of(bites).filter(e->(Arrays.asList(in.split("\\s")).contains(e))).count();
    System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: @YCF_L thanks for the hint. Edited my answer, changed from `String.contains` to `List.contains`.

Comment: It’s a waste of resources to repeat the `Arrays.asList(in.split("\\s"))` operation for every word.

Comment: This is not the correct answer as it doesn't compute separate counting...

Answer (score 8):

How about

```
Map<String, Long> counts = yourStringStream
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

This gives you a Map from all words to their frequency count.

Answer (score 6):

```
Map<String, Long> count = Arrays.stream(bites)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String sentence = "The cat has black fur and black eyes";
String[] bites = sentence.trim().split("\\s+");

Map<String, Long> counts = Arrays.stream(bites)
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Although many examples showing how it's been done with streams are great. You still shouldn't forget that `Collections` already has a method that does this for you:

```
List<String> list = Array.asList(bites);
System.out.println(Collections.frequency(list, "black")); // prints 2
System.out.println(Collections.frequency(list, "cat"));   // prints 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If I can understand your question you can use this solution to get the expected result :

```
String sentence = "The cat has black fur and black eyes";
String in = "black cat";

List<String> bites  = Arrays.asList(sentence.trim().split("\\s+"));
List<String> listIn = Arrays.asList(in.split("\\s"));

long count = bites.stream().filter(listIn::contains).count();
```

**Outputs**

```
3
```

Answer (score 0):

The other simple way is use of [computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) that introduced in java 8

```
  HashMap<String,LongAdder> wordCount= new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (String word:sentence.split("\\s")){
      wordCount.computeIfAbsent(word, (k) -> new LongAdder()).increment();
   }
```

**output**

`{The=1, cat=1, has=1, black=2, fur=1, and=1, eyes=1}`

Answer (score 0):

```
final Collection<String> ins = Arrays.asList(in.split("\\s+"));

Arrays.stream(bites)
    .filter(ins::contains)
    .mapToLong(bite => 1L)
    .sum()
```

Comment: the collecting part can be completly omitted. You just could filter and then use `count()` to get the exact same result

Comment: Completely missed it, the final aggregate result doesn't need any grouping (ty btw).

Comment: You might aswell want to save the list (`Arrays.asList()`) once and not always create a new throw away object in the stream